# Using WinPython; console window closes after running a GUI script.py

Tags: python, windows, qt, cmd, windows-console

this is my first question, but needless to say I've been lurking here all the time.

Currently started converting my code to a GUI application using Qt4. Running WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.3. I've registered the version and it seems that it successfully added the necessary PATH lines.

Now I wanted to make my GUI app run just by double-clicking on the specific specific python script (let's call it `main.py`). This works like a charm, problem is that when I close the GUI window, the console window disappears also. I really want to make it stay, especially when there's a critical error appears that I did not caught - so that I can see python console output - where the problem was.

The code is super simple:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I add a forced error to the code (some random bs) like `w.sss()` the console window will just flash and disappear.

How do I make it stay? Can you guys advise here?

Comment: A GUI app should typically use the .pyw extension, which runs via pyw.exe and pythonw.exe and doesn't create a console. You could support a `--debug` command-line argument that allocates and writes to a console via `AllocConsole()` and `open('\\.\CONOUT$', 'w')`. Then when exiting start a cmd.exe shell via `subprocess.Popen` to keep the console window open.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This sounds a bit more complicated than I initially thought though.

Comment: Load `kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32')`. Then `if kernel32.AllocConsole():` `sys.stderr = open(r'\\.\CONOUT$', 'w');` `sys.stdout = open(r'\\.\CONOUT$', 'w')`. In the `finally` block of a try/finally execute `subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe')`. This way when the Python script exits, the cmd shell still has a reference to the console, which keeps it from being destroyed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! I'll try that out first thing tomorrow.